# Как передается ссылка на экземпляр класса в Java?

Tags: java, android, ооп

У меня есть класс `Class1`, в котором я храню какую-то свою информацию.

В классе `активити А` я создаю экземпляр своего класса `Class1 cl1 = new Class1()`, заполняю данными и передаю эту ссылку в класс следующей активити `ActivityB actB.cl2 = cl1`.

В классе `активити B` поле `cl2` статичное, и доступ к нему внутри пакета. `Активити А` рано или поздно уничтожится системой. Тогда что будет с полем `cl2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `Java` всё передается по значению без исключений. В данном случае будет передана ссылка на объект по значению. При уничтожении `Активити А` с объектом, на который ссылается `cl1`, ничего не произойдет, поскольку на него будет ссылаться объект `cl2` из `Активити B`.

Объект будет удален сборщиком мусора (`GC`), если до него не добраться из так называемых корневых объектов - это объекты, которые доступны вне `Heap`-памяти. К таким объектам относят все локальные переменные из стека, активные потоки, загруженные классы и [другие](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3KLZ/com.ibm.java.diagnostics.memory.analyzer.doc/gcroots.html). В процессе поиска мусора `GC` начинает обход с корневых объектов и постепенно спускаясь по дереву объектов отмечает их как "живые". Соответственно если объект не доступен ни из одного корневого объекта, то он будет удален.

Comment: Можете поподробнее про последнее предложение?

Comment: Немного дополнил ответ